# Make Word movement in ConEmu like linux terminal

Tags: cmd.exe, conemu

How can I set word movement shortcuts like linux terminal in **ConEmu**

- ctrl+A -> Move to the beginning of the line
- ctrl+W -> Delete a word backwards
- ctrl+K -> Delete all words backwards
- ctrl+E -> Move to the end of the line.

How to set like this?
Thanks.

Comment: ConEmu is a Terminal. What you are talking about is a shell responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to install [clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/).

clink provides all the facilities of GNU ReadLine. Just add:

```
"\path\to\clink.exe inject"
```

to the command line of your shell task. Also, in the "features" section of the settings, look for the "Use Clink in prompt" checkbox. It's on the far right, as seen below.[image]

The instructions (one step) are available on the home page, which is the link above.  The executable is very small.